# I want 2 output pins to working alternately

Tags: arduino-uno

I have given pwm output on pin(9) and I Want pin(10) to be high when pin(9) is low and pin(10) to be low when pin(9) is high.  So what should i add to my code?

Comment: "So what should i add to my code"? Know how to use `if ... else ...`?

Comment: Do you care if for few microseconds they are the same?

Comment: That depends on how you achieved your PWM on pin 9. analogWrite? Manual timer manipulation?

I'd set up one of the timers for PWM (timer mode 1 or 3) and have it call its interrupts (OCIExx).
In the interrupt, you'd then alternate between turning each pin on and off.

Answer (score 4):

You can set pin 10 to run in “inverted PWM” mode, and leave
pin 9 in the default non-inverted mode. Pin 9 is the “OC1A”
pin of the AVR microcontroller (output compare of Timer 1,
channel A), whereas pin 10 is OC1B (channel B of the same
timer). Inverting the PWM mode of channel B is a matter of changing
a single bit in one of the control registers of Timer 1:

```cpp
TCCR1A |= _BV(COM1B0);
```

You can do this once in `setup()`, the setting should persist. Then just
`analogWrite()` the same value to both pins. For some background on how
all this works, see the [datasheet of the ATmega328P
microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf) (the MCU at the hearth of your Uno),
especially section 16 “16-bit Timer/Counter1 with PWM” and table
16-3 “Compare Output Mode, Phase Correct and Phase and Frequency Correct
PWM”.

Answer (score 0):

would something like the following work?

```
digitalWrite(9,  !digitalRead(10));
```

like this: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=128698.0

Comment: The link you gave, has set a particular pin as input, but in my case i am giving pwm output from pin9 and i want that when pin 9 output is Low make other pin high and when the pin9 again goes high turn pin10 Low.  But i can't write analogwrite and analog read on same pin9

Comment: it looks like they suggest you can, but also lower down in the forum there is also a suggestion to try and just use a script that sets them as opposites whenever you set one. eg.
void setLed(bool v)
```{
  digitalWrite(9, v);
  digitalWrite(10, !v);
}```